# React Router v4 redirect to requested path after login (Redirected from server side)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-v4, server-side-rendering

I'm using react-router v4 with redux. I managed to implement login with my api server. Currently, I'm implementing redirect if not authenticated.

For that purpose, I created a component `<AuthOnlyRoute>` which basically, returns a `<Redirect>` component if user hasn't logged in. I keep the "from" page to later, return there when users has logged in.

```
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: {
          from: {
            ...otherProps.location, // this is an object where the pathname is kept
            message: 'please, log in', // message to show to the user
          },
        },
      }}
    />
```

This works like a charm if I try to enter a `<AuthOnlyRoute>` and then login. I get redirected to my original route when I render another `<Redirect>` when the user has logged in. I do this in a `<GuestOnlyRoute>`which redirects if the user has already logged in.

However, since in the server side I use a `<StaticRouter>` there's no history (I guess this is the source of my problem, but not really sure) and when I directly request a path which requires auth, the server redirects to to `/login` correctly but the `location` object has no `from` attribute. So, I don't know where to redirect when the users logs in.

How can I solve this problem? How to populate this `location` object from the server?

Thanks in advance